# Disable embedded servlet from loading

Tags: rest, spring-batch, spring-boot

I have a batch application developed with Spring Boot. My batch application needs dependencies from `spring-boot-starter-web`. Specifically I need a REST client with `spring-hateoas` and `jackson-databind` support. How can I disable the embedded Tomcat from starting? What excludes do I need to use?

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(excludes = {
   /** What do I need to put here? */
})
@EnableBatchProcessing
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ComponentScan
public class MyBatchApplication {
  public static void main(String... args) {
    SpringApplication.run(MyBatchApplication.class, args);
  }
}
```

At least, these were not enough, since it ends with an exception:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {
  EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration.class,
  WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class,
  EmbeddedTomcat.class,
  DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.class
})
```

The exception is:

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can explicitly disable web support when you create your application. This means you don't need to exclude any auto-configuration:

```java
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ComponentScan
public class MyBatchApplication {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(MyBatchApplication.class).web(false).run(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I already came to the same conclusion, but had incorrect test configuration still starting the tomcat :)

Answer (score 0):

Late to the show but .web(boolean) is now deprecated in favour of:

new SpringApplicationBuilder(MyApplication.class).web(WebApplicationType.NONE).run(args);

See WebApplicationType for other enum values

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/WebApplicationType.html